# \cshade makes an empty line after, How can I fix?

Tags: highlighting

How can I fix the space added after it?

```
\newcommand{\tccheck}[1]{{\cshade{yellow}{#1}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where's `\cshade` from? Such a fragment of code isn't useful. Post full compilable examples please

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Dear Mr. Hupfer, The problem with me that the final layout of pdf contains an something like empty line before the highlighted part. I use \newcommand{\tccheck}[1]{{\cshade{yellow}{#1}}}
\else
\newcommand{\tccheck}[1]{#1}. when I wants to highlight a part after a superscript digit-like that in the affiliation-an empty line appears after the superscript.

Comment: @user94696: Have you read my comment at all? I did not ask about `superscript` etc, but what `\cshade` is

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it is too long to post as a comment. This is merely to help out user94696, but it is composed of guesswork since it is difficult to understand what the user is trying to accomplish.

Here is my guess at what you are trying to do, after some googling for where \cshade might be coming from. This might of course be totally unrelated. In that case, this is simply an example of and MWE, though Stephen provided a link to a much better one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
}  
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\tccheck}[1]{{\cshade{yellow}{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cshade[2][black]{\bgroup%
%
\color{#2}%
%
\def\UL@start{\setbox\UL@box\hbox\bgroup\everyhbox{\UL@hrest}%
\let\UL@start\@empty \def\UL@unegroup{\bgroup\bgroup}\let\UL@leadtype\@empty%
\bgroup\color{#1}%
\kern-3sp\kern3sp%
\if@ignore\global\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}%
%
\def\UL@leadtype{%
\leaders \hrule \@height\ht\strutbox \@depth\dp\strutbox }%
%
\ULon}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test for no spacing with highlighted text:\tccheck{space?}None!
\bigskip\\
\tccheck{space?}None!

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the efforts to answer an completely unclear question!